# getting input from excel and pass that data to bat file using java

Tags: java, excel, batch-file

I want to read the data from excel and pass those data to batch file using java?

## `test.bat`

```
  `@echo off`
echo /p id = enter your id
```

`echo %id%`

#
Excel file 
1234

How can we retrieve the data from excel file and pass those data to bat file using java
Can anyone please answer this question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to better understand your question and provide you with even better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to read data from excel sheet and then write it to another file.

```
   try {

             InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream("C:/MyWorkSpace/Temp/poi-test.xls"));
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); //sheet of excel

            File file = new File("writedatasamp.txt");  
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator(); 
            while( rows.hasNext() ) {   
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                System.out.println("\n");
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                   writer.write("insert into Emp values(");
                while( cells.hasNext() ) {

                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType()) {
                    System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"     "+cell.getColumnIndex() );
                    if(cell.getColumnIndex()==3)
                  writer.write(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                    else
                     writer.write(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()+","));
                    }
                    else
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType()) {
                        System.out.print( cell.getStringCellValue()+"     " );
                        writer.write("'"+cell.getStringCellValue()+"',");
                    }
                    else
                        if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType()) {
                        System.out.print( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"     " );
                       writer.write("'"+String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"',"));
                        }
                        else
                            if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType())
                                System.out.print( "BLANK     " );
                                else
                            System.out.print("Unknown cell type");


                }

                writer.write(");"+"\n"); 
            }


        } catch ( IOException ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {             try {                 if (writer != null) {                     writer.close();                 }             } catch (IOException e) {                 e.printStackTrace();             }         }
    }
```

Comment: how to pass those values to bat file. The bat file should get the value from excel sheet one by one.

Comment: You will get value here cell by cell only try using logic to write to bat file inside while loop

Comment: Using the above logic i am able to pass parameters into bat file. My bat file has some work. For eg.. you have to give yes or no or some name or many times enter like that.. so I will give all the information on excel sheet and it has to pass the data one by one and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ApachePOI, if you think about doing anything with excel files. Great library to use it with ease!